# Using tensorflow.js on the web

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, inference

Do I need to install any library concerned with `Tensorflow` to inference any model using `Tensorflow.js` on my web brower?

Answer (score 0):

No need to install any library on your computer. You just have to add the  tag that point to the external tensorflow.js latest version script file through the src attribute, like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
```

And that's it. The browser will load all the required tensorflow objects needed for inference...

Comment: I have another question. Now i got a sense to inference deep-learning models such as object detection, classification and segmentation on the chrome browser. And i hope to make the system to make custom model for our users who visit our education site. even though only our user access our education site they can make there custom model for easy experiences for them. And the input data is from our users webcam, images or video files. So our users can inference the model using javascript that you gave us like above.